# Is AMP Project only useful for schema.org/NewsArticle?

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-search-console, structured-data, amp-html

We have recently release our website under AMP format to help the mobile user experience. We have now submitted our sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools, and added the correct `rel="amphtml"`.

However, Webmaster Tools reports all my page with 'Missing supported structured data element' and a link to https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles

I understand that this is needed for the [Top Stories features](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/carousels/top-stories), what I was not aware is that any other Structured Data seems to be not indexed by Google.

Is the AMP useless for non-Article structured data?

Edit: video is also supported.

Answer (score 3):

Depends how people are getting to your AMP page.

At the moment the top stories features is the only place using AMP - unless your website directs people to the AMP pages? So in that sense AMP is only useful for NewsArticle documents at present. Though Google have said this list is likely to grow, quickly.

However if the AMP page is your main page then users will still benefit from the fact your AMP page is fast - even without the NewsArticle structured data tag. Though personally I don't think AMP pages are ready to (or should ever be) completely replace standard HTML.

Will be interesting to see how this changes in future as others (e.g. Twitter) start to integrate AMP pages. Though I'd imagine they'll likely follow Google's lead and demand the same requirements as they do.

Edit 1st March 2016: Google have added a page to the Structured Data site explaining requirements to get in the top stories section: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/carousels/top-stories

Comment: Thanks, I totally share this vision.
My user should be directed to AMP page using the canonical/rel provide by rel="amphtml". This should be an indicator for google search to promote amp page for mobile user (instead of the canonical 'desktop' version). My concern is that none of my page are indexed for this behaviour, as none of my page are NewsArticle.

I think I can only hope for Google Search to grow quickly as you said.

Comment: @BazzaDP So if someone lists products, like ecommerce sites, then they don't benefit currently if they also support AMP pages?

Comment: At present, to be cached in Google, your amp pages need to have either NewsArticle or BlogPosting in them. Even if they didn't have this requirement the AMP pages wouldn't be shown in Google Search results as they are currently only showing them in News carousels (so not sure why they allow BlogPosting for now). Imagine this will change but not see anything to suggest timelines for this. So, yes,  at present supporting AMP on product pages probably won't do much for you.